# Приложение в фоне - PhoneGap

Tags: phonegap, phonegap-api, javascript

Подскажите, если не трудно, возможно ли сделать и / или делал кто-либо подобное на PhoneGap:

Приложение работает в фоне, раз в 10 минут AJAX'ом обращается к серверу - в зависимости от ответа выдаёт нотификейшн в панель уведомлений. Платформы: iOS, Android.

Стоит ли тратить время?

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос был о том, может ли приложение Phonegap работать в фоновом режиме, то [вот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210832/can-phonegap-app-work-in-background).